# Gerrit error says unable to check permissions

Tags: error-handling, gerrit

Gerrit 2.15.1

Something broke in my Gerrit permission settings. 
The story: I removed a Project in the Gerrit UI Projects list, and I checked that I wanted it removed even if there were open changes. But I saw that the project still was in my git-directory on the server. And forced removed it.

Now, as soon as I enter the Gerrit UI it says **Code Review - Error, 500 internal server error.**
I cant view any All: Open or merged changes. My: Change or Watched Changes. I get that error.

In my GERRIT_SITE/logs/error.log I get an error, see below, about unable to check permissions.
But this seems odd to be related to the above story.
Note: I am one of the administrators.

EDIT: My colleague doesn't have the same issue, but we can see that something is broken on my profile. Our logins are connected to Active Directory and we use SSH-keys as authentication.

```
[2018-07-03 13:37:08,162] [HTTP-85] ERROR com.google.gerrit.httpd.restapi.RestApiServlet : Error in GET /changes/?q=is:open+is:wip+owner:self&q=is:open+-is:wip+owner:self&q=is:open+((reviewer:self+-owner:self+-is:ignored)+OR+assignee:self)&q=is:closed+(owner:self+OR+reviewer:self+OR+assignee:self)+-age:4w+limit:10&O=881
com.google.gwtorm.server.OrmException: unable to check permissions
        at com.google.gerrit.server.query.change.ChangeIsVisibleToPredicate.match(ChangeIsVisibleToPredicate.java:67)
        at com.google.gerrit.server.query.change.ChangeIsVisibleToPredicate.match(ChangeIsVisibleToPredicate.java:29)
        at com.google.gerrit.index.query.AndSource.match(AndSource.java:147)
        at com.google.gerrit.index.query.AndSource.readImpl(AndSource.java:101)
        at com.google.gerrit.index.query.AndSource.read(AndSource.java:83)
        at com.google.gerrit.index.query.QueryProcessor.query(QueryProcessor.java:238)
        at com.google.gerrit.index.query.QueryProcessor.query(QueryProcessor.java:174)
        at com.google.gerrit.server.query.change.QueryChanges.query(QueryChanges.java:129)
        at com.google.gerrit.server.query.change.QueryChanges.apply(QueryChanges.java:107)
        at com.google.gerrit.server.query.change.QueryChanges.apply(QueryChanges.java:38)
        at com.google.gerrit.httpd.restapi.RestApiServlet.service(RestApiServlet.java:397)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doServiceImpl(ServletDefinition.java:286)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doService(ServletDefinition.java:276)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.service(ServletDefinition.java:181)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedServletPipeline.service(ManagedServletPipeline.java:91)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:85)
        at com.google.gerrit.httpd.raw.StaticModule$PolyGerritFilter.doFilter(StaticModule.java:451)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
        at com.google.gerrit.httpd.GetUserFilter.doFilter(GetUserFilter.java:75)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
        at com.google.gerrit.httpd.RequireSslFilter.doFilter(RequireSslFilter.java:72)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
        at com.google.gerrit.httpd.RunAsFilter.doFilter(RunAsFilter.java:122)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
        at com.google.gwtexpui.server.CacheControlFilter.doFilter(CacheControlFilter.java:69)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
        at com.google.gerrit.httpd.RequestMetricsFilter.doFilter(RequestMetricsFilter.java:57)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
        at com.google.gerrit.httpd.AllRequestFilter$FilterProxy$1.doFilter(AllRequestFilter.java:133)
        at com.google.gerrit.httpd.AllRequestFilter$FilterProxy.doFilter(AllRequestFilter.java:135)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
        at com.google.gerrit.httpd.RequestContextFilter.doFilter(RequestContextFilter.java:69)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:120)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:135)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:582)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:224)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:512)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:534)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:320)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:283)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:108)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.google.gerrit.server.permissions.PermissionBackendException: not found
        at com.google.gerrit.server.permissions.FailedPermissionBackend$FailedChange.test(FailedPermissionBackend.java:170)
        at com.google.gerrit.server.permissions.PermissionBackend$ForChange.test(PermissionBackend.java:375)
        at com.google.gerrit.server.query.change.ChangeIsVisibleToPredicate.match(ChangeIsVisibleToPredicate.java:65)
        ... 56 more
```

**EDIT**: Since this question, I messed up a bit more and trying to re-init the site instead

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to re-index the index directory and run the Gerrit initialization command again.